# How to detect monotonic decrease in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working with a spark `DataFrame` where I would like to detect any value from a specific column where the value does not monotonically decrease. For those values, I would like to replace them with the previous value according to the ordering criteria.

Here is a conceptual example, if I have a column of value `[65, 66, 62, 100, 40]`. the value "100" is not following the monotonic decrease trend and therefore should be replaced by 62. So the resulting list will be `[65, 66, 62, 62, 40]`.

Below is some code that I created to detect the value that must be replaced however I don't know how to replace the value by the previous and also how to ignore the initial `null` value from the `lag`.

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as psf
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

sc = SparkContext(appName="sample-app")
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)

rdd = sc.parallelize([(1, 65), (2, 66), (3, 62), (4, 100), (5, 40)])
df = sqlc.createDataFrame(rdd, ["id", "value"])

window = Window.orderBy(df.id).rowsBetween(-1, -1)
sdf = df.withColumn(
    "__monotonic_col",
    (df.value <= psf.lag(df.value, 1).over(window)) & df.value.isNotNull(),
)


sdf.show()
```

This code produce the following output:

```
+---+-----+---------------+
| id|value|__monotonic_col|
+---+-----+---------------+
|  1|   65|           null|
|  2|   66|          false|
|  3|   62|           true|
|  4|  100|          false|
|  5|   40|           true|
+---+-----+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if my understanding is correct, shouldn't the 66 also be replaced (by 65) as it does not follow the decreasing trend?

If that is the correct interpretation, then the following should work (I have added an extra column to keep things tidy, but you could wrap everything into a single column creation statement):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

sdf = sdf.withColumn(
    "__monotonic_col_value",
    F.when(
        F.col("__monotonic_col")  | F.col("__monotonic_col").isNull(), df.value)
    .otherwise(
        F.lag(df.value, 1).over(window)
    ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was looking for and you are right, 66 must also be replaced by 65 - Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped